# Visual Studio .NET Debugging: Test new code block using variables in existing stack trace when on breakpoint

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, multiline, breakpoints

I often use the Watch Window in Visual Studio for debugging.  But it requires you put all of your code into a single statement (without a semi-colon) to get the result.  Is there a way I can use existing variables (that are in scope) and write a code block (multiple lines of code) and test it inline while I'm debugging?

---

**Answer until Microsoft makes an enhancement:**
No, this is not possible I guess--having multiple lines (code block) run during debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for such purposes.

So, for instance when the program execution is stopped on a break point and you want to see state of a variable in the current execution scope or even evaluate deffered LINQ query. Just type in variable name and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - variable's value will be printed out. To evaluate LINQ query I'm using `ToList()` and then indexer to acces any particular item, for instance you've such a query:

```
var items = input.Where(i => i.SomeCondition).Take(2);
```

Now just dorp this in Immediate Window:

```
// Count of the items will be printed
items.ToList().Count()

// see first element, element type/name/value/properties/etc will be printed
items.ToList()[0]
```

**Important:** you can evaluate only single line of code at the time.

More advanced usage: [Immediate Window Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171362.aspx)

Comment: +1. Note that there are still plenty of restrictions on what you can do - i.e. it does not allow to have new lambda, multiline statements/new methods/classes.

Comment: Yep, lambda-restriction is weird, Basically I'm using it in a pretty straightforward way - just print some variables, etc. Perhaps any more interesting use-cases are?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so this is not possible for multiple lines?  I tried and tried, and still can't get it to work.

Comment: Not to my knowledge... I never feel need for complicated stuff in immediate window as I'm too afraid to lose some complicated code I could craft in multiple lines :), so I have not looked into other ways to do so.

Comment: My question was asking how to run a block of source code (meaning multiple lines) while debugging.  #1: It sounds like you can only run one line at a time.  You basically have to combine all lines into one.  Is that correct?  #2: If you do run multiple lines, they are all independent of each other, meaning if you set variable x on one line in immediate window, x is not retained if for example you run a new line using x as part of the code, correct?

Comment: In that case, I don't see an advantage to using the Immediate Window over the Watch window if you can only run one line at a time, other than seeing historical values of line of code you ran in there.

Comment: @sll, please state in your answer that your response can only be done with one line of code at a time.  Just mention somewhere that it cannot be done with multiple lines of code and I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @MacGyer: thanks for pointing to this, really one line at the time. Added `**Important:** you can evaluate only single line of code at the time.`